# Python code hangs while trying to open a named pipe for reading

Tags: python, file-io, named-pipes, nonblocking, fifo

I am trying to setup two way communication between a daemon and a client using named pipes. The code hangs while trying to open the named pipe used for input Why?

```
class comm(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self):
    self.srvoutf = './tmp/serverout'
    self.srvinf = './tmp/serverin'
    if os.path.exists(self.srvoutf):
        self.pipein = open(self.srvoutf, 'r') 
        #-----------------------------------------------------Hangs here
    else:
        os.mkfifo(self.srvoutf)
        self.pipein = open(self.srvoutf, 'r')
        #-----------------------------------------------------or here
    if os.path.exists(self.srvinf):
        self.pipeout = os.open(self.srvinf, os.O_WRONLY)
    else:
        os.mkfifo(self.srvinf)
        self.pipeout = os.open(self.srvinf, os.O_WRONLY)
        
    threading.Thread.__init__ ( self )
```

Comment: reads and writes to pipes block until the corresponding reader or writer is connected

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [specification for open()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html):

> When opening a FIFO with O_RDONLY or
> O_WRONLY set:
>
> If O_NONBLOCK is set, an
> open() for reading-only shall return
> without delay. An open() for
> writing-only shall return an error if
> no process currently has the file open
> for reading.
>
> If O_NONBLOCK is clear, an open() for
> reading-only shall block the calling
> thread until a thread opens the file
> for writing. An open() for
> writing-only shall block the calling
> thread until a thread opens the file
> for reading.

In other words, when you open a named pipe for reading, by default the open will block until the other side of the pipe is opened for writing.  To fix this, use `os.open()` and pass `os.O_NONBLOCK` on the read side of the named pipe.